# "Access Denied" when running SQL Server Installation Center Tools

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2019

With MS SQL Server 2019 on Windows Server 2019, I am attempting to do something pretty simple:  Run the "Installed SQL Server Features Discovery Report" tool that comes in the SQL Server Installation Center utility.

But, even though I am in the administrator's group and regardless if I run the Installation Center as admin or not, this pops up:

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Access is denied.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xC5001868%25400xDC80C325

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

There's nothing in the logs that seem to indicate a permissions failure, and unfortunately that URL seems to lead to a sales pitch for the Surface tablet.  Googling the Event ID leads me to something that claims I should uninstall:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/sql-server-native-client-error-mssqlserver-50000?view=sql-server-ver15

That's excessive.

SQL itself runs fine; is there some other permission I need beyond Admin on the machine to run this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - turns out it was McAfee, blocking a browser from launching.  Not having any idea it was a browser that was going to kick off at first, I'd not even thought to check (and no pop-ups are generated by McAfee to hint that way).  Disabling HBSS allows the browser to launch, letting me see the installed features.